# Wrap text to fit width and height in image with PHP and GD?

Tags: php, image, gd, word-wrap

I have seen some examples of wrapping text with PHP and GD to generate image with specified width. But how can I make it to fit with a specified height also, I mean if I have very long text, the script will try to write as much text as possible with wrapping within an image of specified dimension (such as 300x300px)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this piece of code by sk89q, and judging by comments on his blog, it should work on 5.3 :

http://www.sk89q.com/2008/08/ttf-textbox-in-php/

full code source here :

http://www.sk89q.com/pastebin/php/imagettftextboxopt.phps

hope this helps !

Comment: Sir, this does help me a lot, although it's a little bit not meet my requirement (I will try to find a work-around) but I'd say thank you very much!